# Count number of child records in a JSON file using JSON.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have the following JSON file that contains a number of child records. This is a sample of the file:

```
[{
    "dc:type": {
        "dc:title": "CR",
        "dc:type": "recordType"
    },
    "dc:title": "CCP56778974",
    "Submitted_on": "2011-08-16T16:30:01Z",
    "Drawing": "N",
    "Project": {
        "rdf:about": "ALCX",
        "dc:type": {
            "dc:title": "CR_Project",
            "dc:type": "recordType",
            "rdf:resource": "https://ananh.net/2383783"
        },
        "dc:title": "EMBTCE",
        "Name": "EMBTCE-SysDes"
    },
    "history": {
        "oslc_cm:results": [{
            "dc:type": {
                "dc:title": "history",
                "dc:type": "recordType"
            },
            "dc:title": "Modify",
            "new_state": "Analyzed",
            "action_name": "Modify",
            "old_state": "Analyzed",
            "action_timestamp": "2012-03-09T21:18:27Z"
        },
        {
            "dc:type": {
                "dc:title": "history",
                "dc:type": "recordType"
            },
            "dc:title": "Modify",
            "new_state": "Assigned",
            "action_name": "Modify",
            "old_state": "Assigned",
            "action_timestamp": "2012-03-08T23:53:55Z"
        },
        {
            "dc:type": {
                "dc:title": "history",
                "dc:type": "recordType"
            },
            "dc:title": "Modify",
            "new_state": "Submitted",
            "action_name": "Modify",
            "old_state": "Submitted",
            "action_timestamp": "2011-08-16T16:54:56Z"
        }],
        "oslc_cm:collref": "http://UYBNYRTCVV.com/47474"
    },
    "Engineer": {
        "dc:type": {
            "dc:title": "users",
            "dc:type": "recordType"
        }
    },
    "rdf:about": "https://GHNMUN.com/7546756"
}]
```

I need to count the number of "action_name". The result must be 3.
So far I've done this:

```
  Dim jResults As Object = Linq.JObject.Parse(rawdata)
  lRecords = jResults("oslc_cm:results").count
```

but this does not count the child records under [oslc_cm:results].

How can I correctly count the nested "action_name" properties?

Comment: Formatting fixed. Thanks dbc for looking into this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties you are interested in counting, `"action_name"`, are nested deep within your JSON at the paths `"[0].history.oslc_cm:results[0,1,2].action_name"`.  You can use [`JToken.SelectTokens(string path)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) to find and count all such tokens wherever they are in the JSON hierarchy, as `SelectTokens` [supports](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) the [**JSONPath - XPath for JSON**](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query syntax.

If you want to find and count all `"action_name"` properties wherever they are in the JSON hierarchy, you can do:

```
Dim path = "..action_name"

Dim jResults = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(rawdata)
Dim query = jResults.SelectTokens(path)
Dim count = query.Count()
```

If on the other hand you only want to find all `"action_name"` properties in certain specified arrays, you use the following path instead:

```
Dim path = "[*].history.oslc_cm:results[*].action_name"
```

Notes:

- Your outermost [JSON](http://www.json.org/) container is an array -- a comma-delimited sequence of values surrounded by `[` and `]`.  As such it cannot be parsed as a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) which represents a JSON *object* -- a comma-delimited set of name/value pairs surrounded by braces.  Instead you need to parse it into a [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) type that can represent an array.

  I chose [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) which is the abstract base type for any JSON token.  Any well-formed JSON can be parsed into a `JToken`.
- In a JSONPath query, `".."` is the *recursive descent* operator, so `"..action_name"` finds all properties named `action_name` wherever they occur in the JSON.
- In contrast, `"*"` is the *wildcard operator*.  It finds all objects or elements regardless their names at the current location in the hierarchy.  And `"."` or `"[]"` are child operators.

  Thus `"[*].history.oslc_cm:results[*].action_name"` finds properties named `action_name` belonging to all elements of the array property `oslc_cm:results` belonging to the object property `history` belonging to all elements of the root array.
- The correct namespace for `JObject` is [`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm).

Sample working VB.NET fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LW6HLW).

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you so much dbc for this detailed answer!